# Error: Metric Kappa not applicable for regression models

Tags: machine-learning, knn

I tried to use KNN methods to do prediction, I have converted factors to character, and my dataset contains both numeric and characteristic variables, missings have been removed. Here are my R codes:

```
library(caret)
set.seed(142)

ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 5)   
train(LateStage ~ ., 
      data = finalP6, 
      method = "knn", 
      trControl = ctrl, 
      preProcess = c("range"),  
      tuneLength = 10,  
      metric = "Kappa")
```

I obtained this error:

```
You are trying to do regression and your outcome only has two possible values Are you trying to do classification? 
If so, use a 2 level factor as your outcome column. 
Error: Metric Kappa not applicable for regression models
```

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you provide like a example of the data and also explain what you are trying to do with the model.

I assume that you are trying to do classification with kNN, and it is actually ok if your independent variables are factor. For caret you need your dependent variable to be a factor for classification.

First I generate some data that looks like yours, (do not run this to solve your problem):

```
finalP6 = data.frame(LateStage = sample(0:1,1000,replace=TRUE),
matrix(runif(1000),ncol=10))
```

Then run the model and you can see the same error:

```
library(caret)
set.seed(142)

ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 5)
train(LateStage ~ ., data = finalP6, method = "knn", 
trControl = ctrl, preProcess = c("range"),tuneLength = 10,
metric = "Kappa")

Error: Metric Kappa not applicable for regression models
In addition: Warning message:
In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) :
  You are trying to do regression and your outcome only has two possible values Are you trying to do classification? If so, use a 2 level factor as your outcome column.
```

What you need to do is:

```
finalP6$LateStage = factor(finalP6$LateStage)
train(LateStage ~ ., data = finalP6, method = "knn", 
    trControl = ctrl, preProcess = c("range"),tuneLength = 10,
    metric = "Kappa")

k-Nearest Neighbors 

1000 samples
  10 predictor
   2 classes: '0', '1' 

Pre-processing: re-scaling to [0, 1] (10) 
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 5 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 901, 900, 899, 900, 901, 900, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  k   Accuracy   Kappa       
   5  0.4922998  -0.015433129
   7  0.4889058  -0.022246806
   9  0.5027024   0.005380261
  11  0.5074765   0.014693566
  13  0.5090744   0.017946500
  15  0.5100462   0.019756722
  17  0.5048402   0.009260903
  19  0.4868552  -0.027103397
  21  0.4842232  -0.032544799
  23  0.4798550  -0.041286084
```